# Нужно ли кавычить - дело (уголовное) гражданина?

Tags: кавычки

Вопрос: нужно ли кавычить словосочетание дело Иванова (в смысле уголовное)? Например: следствие по делу Иванова зашло в тупик.

Answer (score 2):

**Следствие по делу Иванова зашло в тупик.**

Кавычки не нужны, поскольку это широкоупотребимое выражение, которое употребляется здесь в его обычном значении.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, конечно. Кавычки не нужны.

Даже непонятно, как могла такая идея появиться, это ж не название...
Стул Иванова, письмо Иванова, приключения Иванова, дело Иванова - это конструкции одного ряда.

Другое дело, что это немного разговорная речь, официально оно будет "дело по обвинению Иванова [передано в суд]" - ну или что-то подобное. Но разговорный стиль уж никак не повод для кавычек.